# how to show a element only in post page wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress

There is a div element in header.php which I want to show only in post page. 
The div should not be visible on home page or 404 page or category or pages or tag page. 
It should be only visible post page.

The method I am thinking is using css. The div element will have a class. Let the class be `hide-container` this class is set to `display:none;`. . the trick is show another div `container` in post page.

Like this below code which shows the class in singles.

```
<div class="hide-container <?php if(is_singular() ) { ?>container<?php } ?>">
```

The above code will have worked, but it shows the div element on all pages except home page. I only want the div to be displayed in post page.

thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use the `is_home()` conditional tag

```
<div class="social-tools <?php if(is_home() ) { ?>container<?php } ?>">
```

even though its written like that - `is_home()` shows the posts page

check out this [question](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/14768/determine-if-page-is-the-posts-page)

Comment: i think the question you mentioned is spreading wrong information. you check this link : [link]http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/is_home . is_home is mentioned for home page itself and not for post pages

Comment: **If you select a static Page as your frontpage (see is_front_page()), this tag will be applied to your "posts page".** - taken from that [link](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/is_home) you provided